# Higher volumes of export OR volume of exports?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, comparisons

> The problem gets more complex for India as there are higher volumes of export than that of import.

OR

> The problem gets more complex for India as the volume of exports is higher than that of imports.

which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Export](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/export) has two senses, one is countable, the other isn't. [Oxford]

> 1. [uncountable] the selling and transporting of goods to another country
> 2. [countable, usually plural] a product that is sold to another country
>
>    - *a fall in the value of exports*

My guess is you're talking about different products being exported rather than the process of exporting. Go with `exports` (as evidenced in the example sentence)

Comment: @ArjunParekh: Happy to help :)

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question as to whether to use _volume_ or _volumes_!  Not to mention the fact that "that" is singular and goes with "volume", whereas plural "volumes" would call for "those" in the comparative, so the first example cannot be correct.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Indeed, I glossed over. You think I should edit this to include what you said?

Comment: Yes, but there's more to say. The plural "volumes" could be correct if more than one product, or more than one country, are being compared.  If all exported products are treated as a mass, and only one country is mentioned, singular  "volume" is more apt. Feel free to include this too (if you agree) or I'll put it in a separate answer (no disrepect to yours.)